# Google Maps CameraPosition target displays in the upper left corner of the screen

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I have an issue that is somehow related, maybe you guys can help... The issue is that whatever target I add in the map's camera will appear in the upper left corner instead of the center of the screen. How can I solve this?

[As you can see, the target is the blue marker that appears in the upper left corner...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajrxd.png)

**Edit: I tried on an iPhone X and it worked... apparently the error happens on iPhone 8 and below....**

Comment: It's your current location, if you want to center to that location. You need to animate to the location of yours.

Comment: @salihguler Yes, but it set's my location as the target... but it appears in the upper left corner.

Comment: are you sure that you have that location? If you are sure that it also might be a plugin issue

Comment: @salihguler I am sure, nevertheless I will check the code again...

Comment: @salihguler no, the code is correct. It must be an error of the plugin...

Comment: I tried on an iPhone X and it worked... apparently the error happens on iPhone 8 and below....

Comment: Okay then I would suggest to create an issue in the plugin page with STR

Comment: this is not about dart or flutter or location services. It happens to me when i open up another uicontrolview in my IOS app and get back to map. The center is shifted to top left corner. This issue is about GMSMapview losing the screen margins or something. Did you find any solution your case?